# JavaScript to convert telephone numbers to tel: links

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need some help me with a peice of JavaScript that will convert telephone numbers to tel: links?

Few things I need this code to do: 1) Only find numbers in text, do not find numbers that are located in tag attributes. 2) Once the number is found wrap it in a tel: anchor. 3) Clean up the number for the href attribute (remove anything that is not a number). 4) Hopefully work pretty fast :)

Using jQuery is fine, but I'm not sure if that is the best way.

So the JavaScript will change all instances on the page of something like this:

```
<div data-something-that-looks-like-phone-number="(111) 222-3333"></div> 
(000) 000-0000
```

To this:

```
<div data-something-that-looks-like-phone-number="(111) 222-3333"></div>
<a href="tel:0000000000"> (000) 000-0000</a>
```

You will notice the data-something-that-looks-like-phone-number attribute did not change.

I have a regex that seems to work well for searching for phone numbers

```
[01]?[- .]?[\(\. ]?[2-9]\d{2}[\)\. ]?[- .]?\d{3}[- .]\d{4}
```

Any code to get me started would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Also, there was a similar question earlier and the solution was "do not worry about it because phones do that automatically." That solution does not work for us, we need the tel links even on devices that do not do it automatically. Thanks again...

Answer (score 3):

Pretty old but I encounter this today and couldn't find any valid solution so I wrote this regex and added it as a bookmark button. It messes up the page (css / images) but allow you to click on the number to dial.

```
javascript:document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/((\d[\d\-.]*){9,})/g, '<a href="tel://$1">$1</a>');
```

It will match at least 9 chars with a digit, . or -

---

I must clarify that its just suppose to help you click on a number to dial its not a perfect solution.

****** Update ******

OK, couldn't sleep so I created something much better. Now you just need to click on the number it will be turn to tel link and then just click on it as you would normally do.

```
javascript:document.addEventListener('click', function(e) { e = e || window.event; var target = e.target || e.srcElement; target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML.replace(/(([\d|\(][\d\-.\)\s]*){9,})/g, '<a _was_replaced="true" href="tel://$1">$1</a>'); if (!target.getAttribute("_was_replaced")) { e.preventDefault(); } }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need a regex if you have the data attribute:

```
$("div[data-number]").each(function() {
    var $a = $("<a />").attr("href", "tel:" + $(this).data("number"));
    $a.html($(this).html());
    $(this).html($a);
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/PCHBE/1/)

Comment: thanks for the code, however I just made up the data attribute to show an example of what I do not want to change (a poor example in hindsight). If you run the regex on the whole page source you will find the number in the data attribute, but that should not be changed... The data attribute will not be present in real use, but a similar number might be in a tag somewhere and should be left alone...

Comment: I edited the question to make my use of the data attribute clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
var phoneRegEX = /([01]?[- .]?[\(\. ]?[2-9]\d{2}[\)\. ]?[- .]?\d{3}[- .]\d{4})/;

$("div[data-number]").html(function(i, text) {
   text = text.replace(phoneRegEX, "<a href='tel://$1'>$1</a>");
   return text;
});
```

However your regex seems a bit limited

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that actually works without totally messing up the CSS and images, although it still breaks CSS rules that depend on specific hierarchy because it inserts SPAN elements, so I don't recommend this for general use but it may help in certain cases.

I'm still searching for the perfect solution to this:

```
// Define a function to check if an element is a text node
function isTextNode(node) {
  return node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
}

// Find all elements on the page
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

// Loop through each element and search for phone numbers in text nodes
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const element = elements[i];
  const childNodes = element.childNodes;

  // Loop through the child nodes of the element
  for (let j = 0; j < childNodes.length; j++) {
    const node = childNodes[j];

    // Check if the child node is a text node
    if (isTextNode(node)) {
      const html = node.textContent;

      // Replace phone numbers with links
      const phoneRegex = /([\d|\(][\d\-.\)\s]*){9,}/g;
      const linkTemplate = '<a href="tel:$&">$&</a>';
      const linkedHtml = html.replace(phoneRegex, linkTemplate);

      // Update the text content of the text node if necessary
      if (linkedHtml !== html) {
        const newNode = document.createElement('span');
        newNode.innerHTML = linkedHtml;
        element.replaceChild(newNode, node);
      }
    }
  }
}
```